# Code coverage of just my feature branch

Tags: c#, git, code-coverage

I'm implementing new feature to legacy (poorly tested) system. 
I'm working in separate feature branch and I would like to have my new code fully covered. Is there any tool available, that computes the code coverage, but only for diff between my branch and other specified (master, for example).

I'm using C# and git, but I'm ok with tool for any other platform.

Comment: What do you mean by "diff of the branches"?

Comment: @Ygalbel, I updated the question. I mean diff between my branch and other, I define (trunk, master, branch I'll be eventually merging to...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) that can track code coverage and other metrics by **date**.

So you can view the difference from the branch you start from.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would take is this:

(1) Run a code coverage tool for the master/trunk code (e.g. Open Cover). If this is 0% for the legacy just add an arbitrary test to make it non-zero (0.001% will suffice).

(2) Repeat for your feature branch. If the percentage stays the same or increases then you have made an improvement, if the percentage decreases you've made things worse.

I realise this approach doesn't ensure full 100% coverage of new code in your feature branch (please note that 100% coverage is widely accepted as not a wise investment of time) but you do get code coverage into your master trunk code, which can be used to drive forward a better rest regime in the long run.